# Retweet through looping hashtaRetweet through looping hashtag and media cannot be uploaded with the tweetg and media cannot be uploaded with the tweet

Tags: php, api, twitter, media

I created the scenario in which the user can easily rewteet all the tweets available in the specific hashtag. I used the the some scenario but I will not retweet the tweet, and also stop working or showing 500 internal error. The second issue is related to the media not tweet with the status.